# Do robust estimators like M-estimator still have higher variance than OLS in presence of non-normal errors and/or outliers?

Tags: least-squares, linear, normality-assumption, estimators, unbiased-estimator

In my studies I've learned that even with non-normality of the errors, the OLS estimator is still considered BLUE (Best Linear Unbiased Estimator). The texts also suggested using M and L estimators for robust estimation in those situations.

But if M-estimators like Huber are still linear (correct me if im wrong) estimators, why do we use them?

One reason being suggested often is that even if robust estimators are not "best", they're less sensitive to violations of assumptions or outliers than OLS. However, doesn't being "less sensitive to.." means they have lower variance in those situations? Then how could OLS still be the "best" there?

Comment: BLUE just means you have the best among *linear unbiased* estimators. But if your distribution is far from normal, *all linear estimators* may be poor -- even arbitrarily bad (in typical senses). What use is the best of them then?

Comment: Yea, I just thought M-estimators are still linear estimators so that's where the confusion came from. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M- and other robust estimators are *not* linear in the observations. Note that this is a different issue from fitting a linear model; it concerns how the estimator is computed! In fact being linear in the observations means that outliers cannot be down-weighted, which is what robust estimators aim to do.

In fact they do have (sometimes dramatically) lower variance under heavy tailed error distributions and outlier-generating models (you can simulate this if you want to convince yourself), however they are not better under *all* non-normal distributions. OLS can be better under distributions with lighter tails than the normal.

Note by the way that if you want to be robust against leverage points, you need to do something more sophisticated than a standard M-estimator, for example an MM- or tau-estimator (see robustbase package in R).

Comment: Thank you. So when you say "being linear in the observations means that outliers cannot be down-weighted", does that mean any estimators that plays on the "weight" of observations are not linear? For example, Weighted Least Squares and Generalized Least Squares are also non-linear estimator?

Comment: @wwyws This depends on how the weights are defined. If they are given beforehand, it's linear, but if you want to down-weight outliers, weights for one observation need to depend on where the other observations are, and this causes non-linearity.

Comment: Got it. Really appreciate the explanations!